# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'plugins' of object '#<Mongoose>'

Tags: angular, mongodb

Am currently learning Angular and going through a tutorial T**his guide will walk you through creating a basic MEAN application** https://navakos.slab.com/public/building-a-mean-application-c9369d11?utm_source=mybridge&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=read_more This article uses Babel 6 and am using babel 7 . I have been able to update . However am now getting the error

```
    $ npm run dev

> backend@1.0.0 dev xxx\MEAN_Application\backend
> babel-watch server.js


xxx\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:64
  this.plugins = [];
               ^
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'plugins' of object '#<Mongoose>'
    at Mongoose.Connection (C:\Users\nnamacha\Documents\GitHub\MEAN_Application\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:64:16)
    at Mongoose.NativeConnection [as Connection] (C:\Users\nnamacha\Documents\GitHub\MEAN_Application\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:18:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nnamacha\Documents\GitHub\MEAN_Application\backend\server.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at babelWatchLoader (C:\Users\nnamacha\Documents\GitHub\MEAN_Application\backend\node_modules\babel-watch\runner.js:51:13)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\nnamacha\Documents\GitHub\MEAN_Application\backend\node_modules\babel-watch\runner.js:62:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nnamacha\Documents\GitHub\MEAN_Application\backend\node_modules\babel-watch\runner.js:110:21)
    at process.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:876:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

My package.jason

```
 {
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "babel-watch server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-watch": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.9"
  }
}
```

Below is my server.js

// server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose, { connection } from 'mongoose';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Connects to the MongoDB database collection.
mongoose.Connection('');
const Connection = mongoose.Connection;

connection.once('open',() => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully!')
});
app.use('/',router);


// Establishes which port the backend runs on.
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Express server running on port 4000'));
```

What could i be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error message as you! I think your first issue is that you are not actually connecting to your database, try this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/', {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
var connection = mongoose.connection;
```

Let me know if this helps!